# Terms against Time in Kibana

Tags: logstash, kibana

I'm using Logstash/Kibana to store Apache logs.

Is it possibly to draw a line graph of a count of each "HTTP Status Code" against Time?  Or indeed a count of each entry in any finite set of terms against time?

I can't see a way to do it using the Terms or Histogram panels. The only way I can think to do this is using pinned queries with one query per term (e.g. "http_status: 404" etc) and a histogram, but that would mean specifying each term/query individually which is horrible clunky.

Is there a better way that I have missed that can do this automatically?

Answer (score 1):

In version 3.0.1, you can use a TopN query to achieve that.
From [this blog post](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/whats-cooking-kibana/):

> Click the colored dot next to a query to do more than set the query color. The new top-N query finds the most popular terms in a field and uses them to compute new queries.

[image]